# How do I plot in Rstudio if I have a column of data? a total of 55 rows in the column. I need to schedule them

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my data. I made a graph in Gwyddion and just now i am learning R and want to practice. I opened this file  in R studio, than what should i do?
plot()
lines() ? But what should i write there? Sorry, i am a new

```
6.43928e-08
8.9657e-08
3.5973e-08
7.98486e-08
1.45126e-07
1.19643e-07
6.56901e-08
1.56191e-07
6.04781e-08
7.87716e-08
5.28275e-08
8.52068e-08
5.74379e-08
6.63155e-08
9.4133e-08
4.47355e-08
5.00223e-08
1.25508e-07
1.44894e-08
1.38814e-07
1.33138e-07
8.93863e-08
8.29701e-08
3.51607e-08
5.78949e-08
6.4056e-08
9.40513e-08
1.13815e-07
1.13724e-07
1.86738e-07
9.95791e-08
1.32434e-07
1.07028e-07
4.06969e-08
1.32302e-07
6.96083e-08
1.28238e-07
6.14803e-08
5.97798e-08
1.12871e-07
1.92305e-07
2.01796e-07
1.09566e-07
2.41609e-07
1.72438e-07
6.86917e-08
9.86971e-08
1.22608e-07
1.14464e-07
9.12973e-08
8.28016e-08
8.89075e-08
7.71099e-08
9.74162e-09
2.53372e-08
```

I tried to write it py plot() but it was not succesfiull

Comment: Please study some tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ilya Hibrikov! I don't know of any StackExchange sites that are intended to be used as complete *tutorials* or *lesson plans*, and SO is no exception. While many answers do have sufficient detail to be useful as a mini-howto or such, I believe that that is the exception. And asking for that much is off-topic, please see [help/on-topic]. Having said that ... what have you tried? What didn't work? Questions on SO are expected to include _"what I tried"_ and _"what did not work"_. Good luck!